# Importing project module TO project subdir, WITHOUT relative path

Tags: python, import, pycharm, project, directory-structure

This **must** have been asked before, but I cannot for the life of me find it.

I have a project structure something like this

```
ROOT
├── README.md
├── modules
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mod1.py
│   └── mod2.py
├── tests
│   ├── test_mod1.py
│   └── test_mod2.py
├── notebooks
│   ├── nb1.ipynb
│   ├── nb2.ipynb
│   └── sub_dir
│       ├── sub_nb.ipynb
│       ├── generate_py
│       └── py_files
│           └── sub_nb.py
├── definitions
└── main.py
```

So from `main.py` I am able to import anything from `definitions`, or any module from `ROOT/modules`.

What I want is to be able to import from these from anywhere within the `notebooks` directory tree. I know I *could* do this using:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

But the `notebooks` directory tree has many layers, and I don't want my code to start looking like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../../../../")
```

What's more, the file `generate_py` is a bash script, that converts the jupyter notebooks (`.ipynb`) to `.py` files and stashes the `.py` files into the `./py_files` subdir.

With the above method i end up having to manually edit every file to put an extra `../` into the `sys.append()`. This is annoying.

If I run files from within pycharm all works well (I'm guessing it updates your PYTHONPATH to include the project root when you create `main.py`?)

To further complicate, this project is run on several machines, shared via git. So absolute references are out.

But running from terminal, or from within jupyter it cant gind modules, or definitions without going through the `sys.append()` process. And I feel there must be a better way.

So what is the best practice here?

Comment: Instead of adding ROOT to your `PYTHONPATH` dynamically in every file, every time it runs, you can add it by modifying the environment variable, i.e. add `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/ROOT"` to your `.bashrc` or similar. Since ROOT might be in different locations on different users' machines, you should either have a README telling users to do this, or else a `setup` shell script which [computes the path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/6445069) and does this automatically.

Comment: I did mean `generate_py`.

Comment: I did think about editing PYTHONPATH in .bashrc, but it still seems a bit inelegant. I will then forever expose any project I work on to accidentally importing from `definitions`, when I inevitably forget to remove the line later. I still feel there must be a cleaner way.

Comment: You can use `virtualenv` (optionally also `virtualenvwrapper` for a nicer experience) to make an environment on a per-project basis, and add the `export PYTHONPATH...` to the environment's `activate` script instead, to avoid polluting your `.bashrc`